# AraBERT Overfitting for sentiment analysis

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, bert, sentiment-analysis

I Am newbie to Machine Learning in general. I am currently trying to follow a tutorial on sentiment analysis using BERT and Transformers.

[image]

I do not know how i can Read the results to know the overfitting case. Can any one help me to read this and explain to me how to know it afterwards.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I'm not knowledgeable about this type of model but your results show very high overfitting: at every epoch the training loss decreases (good) but the validation loss increases (bad), thus increasing the difference between the two values. The validation loss should be as close as possible to the training loss, and certainly not increase.

Comment: @Erwan thank u so much. Very helpfull.

Comment: @amal If you would like to gain some general understanding of learning curves and how to interpret train/val/test losses [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/95029/84891) and [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/88170/84891) question might be worth reading.